# Task Manger vs Performance Monitor: CPU Usage, Why are they so different?

Tags: windows, cpu, performance

Can anyone explain the difference between CPU utilization in Task Manager and Performance Monitor in Windows?

In the following screenshot I'm running a powershell script that just does a few recursive loops. The overall CPU usage is similar: 42% in TM and 39% in PM, but look at the `pwsh.exe` process. Why is it SO different?

[image]

Comment: I believe I figured it out. Long story short is that we're right, and Task Manager is wrong. Kinda. The output you're seeing from the `processes` tab is being calculated using the `\Processor Information(*)\% Processor Utility` counter. This is why you can find the process under the details tab, and it will show a different CPU percentage. The CPU  usage under details is being listed from the `\Process(*)\% Processor Time` counter